# OpenAi ChatGPT Start of EventStream Messages Not Valid

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api, chat-gpt-4

With php I implemented the ChatGPT API using StreamedResponse which worked fine so far but I started to encounter a strange behaviour I have no explanation for.

The first $data response is suddenly not a valid format anymore as the output is the first response and half of the second one.

First response:

```
data: {"id":"chatcmpl-8JMm7OUjW9DSVoSieJAnterQ3Lv2w","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1699626471,"model":"gpt-4-0613","choices":[{"index":0,"delta":{"role":"assistant","content":""},"finish_reason":null}]}

data: {"id":"chatcmpl-8JMm7OUjW9DSVoSieJAnterQ3Lv2w","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1699626471,"model":"gpt
```

Second response:

```
-4-0613","choices":[{"index":0,"delta":{"content":"Gr"},"finish_reason":null}]}
```

The code did not change and worked before.

My assumption is that either there is some bug on OpenAis end or something changed I am not aware of.

I can rule out that it has something to do with my quota limits. Also the used model seems unlikely to me.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this post](https://community.openai.com/t/malformed-streaming-answers-from-gpt-4-completions-api-lately/481686) in their community.

It was a bug at OpenAIs end. The issue resolved itself.

My learning:

- changing the model did not help
- changing API Keys did not help

If an event source stream does not return proper data their isn't really anything you can do about it on your end.